# Icon fonts : some icon display as text instead on my machine

Tags: fonts, material-design, font-face, webfonts, icon-fonts

**This is an issue about how my machine sees the web, not a personal web project.**
On my machine, some icon fonts display as literal text (the name of the icon) instead of the graphic icon itself.

**Environnement**

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
- MacOS Sierra 10.12.3
- Happening using Chrome, Safari and Firefox browsers in their latest versions

**Also**

- I use a decent internet connexion and the font file does not fail to load
- I do not use a proxy and do not live in China
- The problem still happens when disabling all the browser extensions.
- EDIT : I have no error/warning at all in the browser console.

For example, this is how I see https://developers.google.com/web/
[image: google-icons-not-showing]

and https://material.io/icons/
[image: material-icons-not-showing]

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please open the developer console and check for the error messages

Comment: What if you check the style of those bad elements with the inspector?

Comment: Here's what I see https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/btpicpkaxfptrmb/2017-04-05%20at%2013.11.png
Style is applied, it only looks like the custom font is not rendered

Comment: Is it possible that your system has an incompatible version of "Material Icon" font? (Check in FontBook.app)

Comment: Yes. That was it. I must have installed another broken font named the same.

Comment: Glad that helps. I'll post an answer after reaching a real computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The webpages OP has shown uses the [Material Icons](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web) font via [Google Web Fonts](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/technical_considerations). They serve a CSS file like:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Material Icons'), 
       local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), 
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v21/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5UEw0lE80llgEseQY3FEmqw.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  ...
}
```

It will always try to load the local version of "Material Icons" font first, before the web font. Therefore, if OP has an [outdated](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/205) or customized version of "Material Icons", the desired effect won't be shown.

To fix this, delete the local "Material Icons" font, or replace it with the [latest version](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/iconfont) if you still want a local copy.

Comment: Just what I needed.  Thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: I just came across this because I was searching to see why some icons show up and some don't when using the local version. I did already assume they are outdated even though they have not been updated since 2016 and replaced them, same result, any ideas what else can cause this? TIA.