# Angular Material mat-icon displaying strange characters?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular material button as following:

[image]

```js
<mat-icon matTooltip="Petición" *ngIf="addRequest" (click)="addSolicitud(element)" class="addSolicitud">add</mat-icon>
```

Some users are experiencing a strange behaviour with the same browser (Chrome). This is displayed:

[image]

The same is happening with other icons:

- `menu` icon displays the following character: `ú`
- `info` and `notifications` icon are not displaying anything

No console error is displayed.
No proxy is being used.

Any idea on what is going on here? Some users are experiencing this behaviour but others are not.

Comment: Check your meta tag once it should be set to `utf-8`

Comment: @uiTeam324 meta tag is set to `utf-8`

Comment: @Iñigo Have you changed `font-family` in css for `mat-icon` or `addSolicitud`? The `font-family` must be 'Material Icons'

Comment: @ivangreek no, and it's only failing for some users

Comment: Take a look on this post [Icon fonts : some icon display as text instead on my machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143794/icon-fonts-some-icon-display-as-text-instead-on-my-machine). It may be useful

Comment: @user1241241 which one?

Comment: @lnigo there is a bug there

Comment: @user1241241 where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143794/icon-fonts-some-icon-display-as-text-instead-on-my-machine) the user was loading a local version of "Material Icons" font. If used a Private Navigation tab everything worked fine, so he had to remove the browser info and the problem was solved.